# Android platform not supported in SUP

Tags: android, sybase, sup

I want to build a native application using Android, but when I try to "Generate Code" in SUP, I can't find Android platform in the choices.

Can someone please help me ?

In the SUP installation, I selected the "Evaluation License (30 days trial)". Can this be the problem ? I mean, if I chose Unserved or Served licenses, I will find Android platform in it ?

Answer (score 1):

SUP supports Android only after SUP 2.0 release. Please check the version you are using and kindly update the SUP mobile SDK to get the support

Answer (score -1):

In order to generate Android code from SUP, you have to:

- install [Android SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r21.1-windows.exe) on your computer.
- start android SDK, and install at least 1 version of Android API (for example Android 4.0)
- install Android Developer Tools (ADT) to your Sybase Unwired Workspace ide. Installation guide for ADT is [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)